# wp8 how do i tell if a user has rated my app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, marketplace

I can get a user to rate my windows phone 8 app by displaying the REviewTask.  However, I can't tell if they actually submitted a rating.

Is there some way to tell if a user of my app has rated it?

For bonus points, can I tell what rating they gave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no way to tell this. You may be able to retrieve a list of reviews (and related informations such as rate, user name, device model), but you can't associate them to a specific Windows phone device.

I would advice to generate a code for users who are using your app and then make them type it into the review. So that, when you fetch the list of reviews, if you are able to find that code, the user rate your app. You can finally also check which rating they gave you.

Comment: User also can just delete his rate after you check that fact. So I'd prefere just to trust them.

Comment: Exactly, you are also likely to get the opposite result having users to rate just one star. What I advised is a workaround, but I would never use it.